# PHP Checkbox from Form

Tags: php

Trying to get a value from this checkbox but it's not working..

Should be a simple yes or no .. however nothing is happening .. always defaults to the else statement.

```
<form id="edit_donor_form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
      method="post" name="switch">
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="switchq" value="Yes" >
  </label>
  <input name="submit" type="button" value="submit" />
</form>
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['switchq'] == 'Yes') {
     echo "Hover On.";
   }
   else {
     echo "Hover Off";   
   }    
?>
```

Comment: Change your submit input from type="button" to type="submit" this may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your form not has submit botton, the input type that you used was `button` you need to change it to `submit`

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
```

Comment: +1 anyway. Since both answers were almost the same, I deleted mine :)

Answer (score 0):

If You dont't want change input type="button" to type="submit", You can add:

```
<input name="submit" type="button" value="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('edit_donor_form').submit();" />
```